# Unable to install ubuntugis

Tags: 18.04, ppa

```
 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 10):

For now, if you wish to use the ubuntugis ppa with Ubuntu 18.04, you will need to use the *unstable* repo, not the stable one.  Remove (or comment out) the entries for the stable repo (probably in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list`) and run the following (as per the [ubuntugis wiki](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable) ) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable`
still results in
`E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.`
using Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: So I renamed the `ubuntugis-ubuntu-ubuntugis-unstable-cosmic.list` file to `ubuntugis-ubuntu-ubuntugis-unstable-bionic.list`, then edited the file changing `cosmic` to `bionic`. Then `sudo apt update` completed without complaining.

Comment: @BeerMe, the problem is both for bionic and cosmic, and you have cosmic, so I am not sure how that worked for you. Nonetheless, can explain in more detail how you made the changes?  Where do I find that file and how to change its name? Thanks

Comment: @icypy The files are under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. I should point out that making those changes allowed me to run `apt update` without  problems, but I never did get ubuntugis to work.

Answer (score -6):

Here's your problem, and the cause of further errors (`E:`) and notifications (`N:`):

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release           
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

The `404` error means you failed to connect to `ppa.launchpad.net`.

Fix your network connection.

Comment: No, I dont understand wh it gives that error for this particular package , I am able to update other packages from the repository. It's just this repository that fails.

Comment: No "bionic packages" in http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/ → http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: `404` does not mean he cannot connect, but there is just no bionic in ubuntugis ppa yet.

Comment: the last available packages in  ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu  so far is xenial